# Define text wrapping point outside the parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible, using CSS/JS/jQuery/etc. to define the wrapping point for text outside the parent element?

The reason for me asking this is that I'd like to be able to split text into smaller pieces while still giving the impression that it's all contained in one element. For example imagine a div that's 300px wide and tall, and has text as it's content. I'd like to be able to split this div into a grid of 3 x 3 divs that are all 100px x 100px but give the appearance of continuous text, by manipulating text positioning inside the smaller divs.

Since this is a bit hard to explain, here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

Reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to do some CSS3 3D transformations with the text without turning into an image, see for example http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/ --> Tiles3D

Is this possible?

Comment: why o you want to split the text like this? Surely you'd rather split in inside the sentence?

Comment: Because I want to be able to do some CSS3 3D transformations with the text without turning into an image. See for example http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/ --> Tiles3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve a blockwise 3D transform effect, there may be another solution:

You could duplicate the text-div into every div block and position it with `position: absolute;` in every block and hide it with `overflow: hidden;`. You will then have again the impression that this is one big text block.

Then you are able to transform those divs blockwise.

I built a short Fiddle to show you how I mean it, should work quite well:

> **[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pXZZ/2/)**

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Well done giving a perfect answer even though my question wasn't perhaps the clearest ever asked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CSS3 Columns can help:

```
#con{background-color: #DDDDDD;
padding: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #888888;
text-align: left;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 35px;
-moz-column-gap: 35px;
column-gap: 35px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZutY/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this doesn't quite achieve the effect I was looking for. See the link I added to the question for a better explanation of what I'm looking for.

Comment: why dont you check the read me file at githiub https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider